# Navigation menu empty

Tags: installation, navigation

I installed Drupal 9 and CiviCRM 5.60 with Composer,
and adapted docroot in cPanel including the web folder: http://domainname.ext points to public_html/web

Navigating to the CiviCRM Navigation Menu settings, the items list is empty, only showing an "image not found" image (see screen shot)

[image]